# How hardware write a byte in memory?

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-management, memory-hardware, memory-access

I want to know how hardwares write a byte in memory?
If there is difference between writing process in RAM and ROM I would like to know as well.

Specially I want to know:

1. Is hardware writes values bit by bit? (I mean like writing first bit then go to next)
2. Is there a header that move around and change bit by bit? If not how it is working?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory

Comment: Thanks @D.W. it seems that it is not bit by bit, but each time changing a bit-line (could have multiple columns or rows, I guess)

Comment: ROM stands for Read-Only Memory. So, no writes !

Comment: There have been *very* different implementations, even narrowed to *main* memory. The bit serial ones (delay lines, magnetic drums) were marginalised by *(magnetic) core memory* by  1955. I think *bubble memory* to be the weirdest one: moving *magnetic domains* relative to something that can be considered read- and write heads, bit serial for each *loop*, used for persistent storage.